# Cron task set to change Gnome 3 background doesn't update the background

Tags: gnome, cron, fedora-36

I've made this simple script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# If started as root, then re-start as user "cyril":
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
    exec sudo -H -u cyril $0 "$@"
fi

wget -q -O /tmp/wallpaper.jpg https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?landscape,mountain,forest,stars,space,galaxy;
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark file:///tmp/wallpaper.jpg;
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///tmp/wallpaper.jpg;

exit 0;
```

Moved it to /etc/cron.hourly/1wallpaper and gave it a chmod +x.

If I run it manually from the bash, it works fine.
Being on cron.hourly should run it every hour, giving me a different background every hours, but it's not the case, nothing changes between the hours.

What am I missing?

I ensured the user running the `gsettings` is me, in order to not change the background of the root user.

I'm wondering if, when running with cron, another type of shell is run that is not compatible with what I'm doing.

I'm using Fedora 36.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a suggestion to troubleshoot this further. Can you add this script to your crontab with `crontab -e`, let it [run every minute](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*) and pipe the stderr and stdout to a file `/your/script.sh >> /tmp/yourlog.log 2>&1` such that you can read any errors that come up?

Comment: Here is a relevant question from the Ubuntu SE: https://askubuntu.com/q/742870/1366419

Comment: Thank you for this, you put me on the right track and I did post an answer to the question linked to your comment that works for me. If you post an answer, I can reward you the bounty.

Comment: That narrows it down pretty well.  More generally, keep in mind that cron does NOT have necessary environment variables loaded.  Often, paths need to be set also.  I wouldn't have known which vars were missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question over at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/742870/1366419) treats the same problem.
The core of [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437023/1366419) is to provide `cron` with the correct value of the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable.